# Cumulative probability curves using inverse gamma distribution in R

Tags: r, probability-density

How to plot cumulative magnitude-frequency curve using the Inverse Gamma Distribution in R using ggplot, to make a graph similar to the one below

Data is here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvhhxbws66ttwmq/area.csv?dl=0

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create exactly the same plot or is it enough with a function that creates inverse gamma distributions like `dinvgamma()` from  the package `invgammav`. You can check examples [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/invgamma/README.html)

Comment: Exactly the same as this one

Comment: I have the area data and can provide if needed

Comment: I recommend adding the data in OP to facilitate others creating the plot

Comment: I have provided the data in a link